# WPF ApplicationCommands with PRISM

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm redesigning an application to work with prism. The current application has some open/save/save as, ... routed commands implemented in a viewmodel that corresponds to a shellviewmodel. Usig a behavior the commands are added to the window's commandbindings. In the new design this logic doesn't belong in the shell but in a module.

To complicate matters this module doesn't have a view active before an 'open' command has been handled. So even if I were to add to the commandbindings of a view this would not work because there would be nothing to route to. I do have a view that is added to a ribbonbar but that works through an adapter that merges with the shell ribbonbar and detaches the merged elements from their old parent into the main ribbon, preserving the DataContext of each element (similar to https://prismribbonregionadapter.codeplex.com) It doesn't feel right to try and put add to the commindbindings there just to make it work.

This seems like a common problem and yet I'm not finding any information about it. Would it be a good idea to use a service for this somehow? Let the shellvm bind to the shell commandbindings and expose those through an interface? Any advice on how to tackle this?